# Editing tags in bulk that make no improvement

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

Looked at the main page and there were half the page filled up with questions years old that had the page updated. The updates did not really improve the question or search ability.

i.e. tags [data0loader, sfdc, loader] edit was to remove sfdc and loader.

[Cannot login to Apex dataloader 18.0](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/95266/cannot-login-to-apex-dataloader-18-0?noredirect=1#comment188849_95266)

What is the communities idea of this, keeping in mind that edits to 20 ors so questions places the new question down or off the front page.

Comment: Likely related to my question about how to kill the `[salesforce-crm]` tag.

Comment: A necessary evil if we want to get rid of some tags as far as I've understood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought the tag burnination process specifies:

> This is a manual process which involves going to each individual question and editing it to remove the tag, *along with fixing any other issues with each question*.

[Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work)

Shouldn't edits made to those older questions either fix additional issues in the question, or close those older questions, in order to prevent exactly this situation?

Comment: So for unanswered questions we could also add an answer as well as removing redundant tags. I've only been taking tags off older questions when the 'community' account pushes them back into the active list, where they will fall out again pretty rapidly.

Comment: Yeah that's a pretty good strategy @Dave

Comment: That's why I use the newest sort order most of the time. Active tends to be less helpful.